# How to print the value of a variable after every round in matlab?

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I have  100 nodes using following for loop:

```
xm1=100;      %diameters of sensor network
ym1=100;

sink1.x=50;  %distance of base station from the network
sink1.y=120;

nl = 100;         %no of nodes

pl=0.1;          %probibilty of a node to become cluster head
El1= 0;
Eint=0.5;          %energy supplied to each node 
Etl =0 ;
for i=1:1:nl
    Sl(i).xd=rand(1,1)*xm1;         %it will distribute the nodes in 1 dimension in x axis randomly.
    XR(i)=Sl(i).xd;                 %we store its value in xr
    Sl(i).yd=rand(1,1)*ym1;           %it will distribute the nodes in 1 dimension in y axis randomly
    YR(i)=Sl(i).yd;
    Sl(i).id = i;
    Sl(i).G=0;                        % as the no of node that have been cluster head is zero 0
    Sl(i).E=Eint; %%*(1+rand*a);     
    %fprintf(' Sensor node energy:  %15f \n',Eint);   %?
    %initially there are no cluster heads only nodes
    Sl(i).type='N';
end
```

cluster formation took place like tis

```
for r=1:1:rmax
     for i=1:1:nl
            if(Sl(i).E>0)
                temp_randl=rand;
                if ( (Sl(i).G)<=0)

                    if(temp_randl<= (pl/(1-pl*mod(r,round(1/pl)))))
                        countCHsl=countCHsl+1;
                        packets_TO_BSl=packets_TO_BSl+1;
                        PACKETS_TO_BSl(r+1)=packets_TO_BSl;
                        Sl(i).type='C';
                        Sl(i).G=round(1/pl)-1;
                        Cl(clusterl).xd=Sl(i).xd;
                        Cl(clusterl).yd=Sl(i).yd;
                        distancel=sqrt( (Sl(i).xd-(Sl(n+1).xd) )^2 + (Sl(i).yd-(Sl(n+1).yd) )^2 );
                        Cl(clusterl).distance=distancel;
                        Cl(clusterl).id=i;
                        X(clusterl)=Sl(i).xd;
                        Y(clusterl)=Sl(i).yd;
                        clusterl=clusterl+1;
                        distancel;
                        if (distancel>do)
                            Sl(i).E=Sl(i).E- ( (ETX+EDA)*(4000) + Emp*4000*(distancel*distancel*distancel*distancel ));
                        end
                        if (distancel<=do)
                            Sl(i).E=Sl(i).E- ( (ETX+EDA)*(4000)  + Efs*4000*(distancel * distancel ));
                        end
                    end

                end
                % S(i).G=S(i).G-1;

            end
        end
        STATISTICS.COUNTCHS(r+1)=countCHsl;

        for i=1:1:nl
            if ( Sl(i).type=='N' && Sl(i).E>0 )
                if(clusterl-1>=1)
                    min_disl=Inf;
                    min_dis_clusterl=0;
                    for cl=1:1:clusterl-1
                        templ=min(min_disl,sqrt( (Sl(i).xd-Cl(cl).xd)^2 + (Sl(i).yd-Cl(cl).yd)^2 ) );
                        if ( templ<min_disl )
                            min_disl=templ;
                            min_dis_clusterl=cl;
                        end
                    end


                    min_disl;
                    if (min_disl>do)
                        Sl(i).E=Sl(i).E- ( ETX*(4000) + Emp*4000*( min_disl *min_disl * min_disl * min_disl));
                    end
                    if (min_disl<=do)
                        Sl(i).E=Sl(i).E- ( ETX*(4000) + Efs*4000*( min_disl * min_disl));
                    end
                    Sl(Cl(min_dis_clusterl).id).E =Sl(Cl(min_dis_clusterl).id).E- ( (ERX + EDA)*4000 );
                    packets_TO_CHl=packets_TO_CHl+1;

                    Sl(i).min_disl=min_disl;
                    Sl(i).min_dis_clusterl=min_dis_clusterl;
                else
                    min_disl=sqrt( (Sl(i).xd-Sl(n+1).xd)^2 + (Sl(i).yd-Sl(n+1).yd)^2 );
                    if (min_disl>do)
                        Sl(i).E=Sl(i).E- ( ETX*(4000) + Emp*4000*( min_dis1 *min_dis1 * min_dis1 * min_dis1));
                    end
                    if (min_disl<=do)
                        Sl(i).E=Sl(i).E- ( ETX*(4000) + Efs*4000*( min_disl * min_disl));
                    end
                    packets_TO_BSl=packets_TO_BSl+1;
                end
            end
        end

end
```

Now I have to print value of S1(i).E for all i after every round?
Means I have to print remaining energy of all nodes at every round.

Thanks in advance.
And the exact answer of this question is

```
fprintf('%0.2f \n',Sl(:).E);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume *r* stands for round, so you could add any of the following lines right before your last *end* to print the remaining energy:

- sprintf('%0.2f \n',Sl(:).E);
- disp([Sl(:).E]');
- Sl(:).E

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have to find energy of each node at each round.e.g. let I have three nodes. Initial energy of every node is 1 joule. After 10 round initial energy of node 1 is 0.6, node 2 is 0.5 , node 3 is 0.7.  How to print this? When I used sprintf('%0.2f', S1(i).E) before last end of program. It is giving 1.42.

Comment: When I used disp(S1(i).E) .It is printing value of 100th node at each round. How to print value of all nodes at a round. Also how to save these results in to a file.

Comment: I have updated the answer to print all values at each round. Also save to a file is another question. That would depend on what file format you want. But you could try: fid=fopen('myfile.txt'); fprintf('%0.2f \n',Sl(:).E); fclose(fid); for a txt file. If I have answered your question please consider accepting it so others may benefit from it if they face similar problems.

Comment: Thanks a lot. yes now energy of every node is printing on a file using following lines  fid1=fopen('Energy_every_round.txt','w');
fprintf(fid1, '%s\t%s\t\n','NUM','energy');
fprintf(fid1,'%0.2f \n',Sl(:).E);  fclose(fid); But only energy value is  printing  in the file. I want to see node id also. Is there any way of doing this? i.e. printing both node ID and node energy on the file. Please provide answer. I will mark it as accepted immediately.

Comment: This is just giving energy of 100th node.    NUM energy 
100, 0.05 
1.095687e-01, 0.04 
1.309674e-02, 0.15 
1.130597e-01, 0.14 
4.986763e-02, 0.10 
1.156074e-01, 0.07 
1.078232e-01, 0.13 
1.678386e-01, 0.07 
8.742347e-02, 0.06 
1.116080e-01, 0.06 
7.889621e-02, 0.10 
5.088216e-02, 0.10 
2.253168e-02, 0.10 
9.302112e-02, 0.07 
1.227539e-01, 0.10 
2.282807e-02, 0.08 
8.708028e-02, 0.07 
3.589620e-02, 0.11 
1.164451e-01, 0.08 
7.880229e-02, 0.16 
1.275763e-01, 0.05 
3.319550e-02, 0.05 
1.663428e-02, 0.00 
2.107233e-02, 0.08 
1.110767e-01, 0.07 
8.944071e-02, 0.01 
7.116244e-02,

Comment: I'm sorry, try fprintf('%d, %0.2f \n',r,Sl(:).E), just before the last end (right before r update)

Comment: I want to ask. How to edit comment. I want to give you actual output. But howto give it ina proper way. I tried ctrl+k . but of no use. WhenI tried fprintf('%d, %0.2f \n',r,Sl(:).E) following output is coming for all rounds r =

        1000

1000, 0.02 what is 0.02 here, is this energy ?   3.698363e-02, 0.10 
5.033638e-02, 0.08 
2.532137e-02, 0.13 
8.703447e-02, 0.06 
1.040075e-01, 0.13  what is first column indicating here?

Comment: what is 4.508183e-01 this type of values?

Comment: These are just the values stored in Sl(:).E in scientific notation (0.4508186 in your example). I forgot to remove one argument in the last ocmment. sprintf('%d, %0.2f ',r,Sl(:).E) is what you are looking for. The first column is the round and the others are the Energy, delimited by commas. I believe you can only edit a comment if it is the last one.

Comment: Thanks a lot for explanation. Can you tell me how  to lift ban from asking questions?

Comment: Sorry, but I have no clue

Answer (score 0):

a simple
 S1(i).E, 
should work.

Comment: Some more detail would be helpful here.

Comment: i meant if you put a comma after any variable its value will be printed